# Show that the following set is open

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following set is open. $$S = \{(v,w,x,y,z) \, \epsilon \,\mathbb R ^5 \,|\, x^2e^{v + w^{100}} > 2 \;and\; xy-z^2 < -1\} \subset \mathbb R^5$$

Hint: Use the following theorem. Let f be a function from $\mathbb R^n \, to \,\mathbb R^m$ Then, f conts $\iff f^{-1}(U) $ is open for each open set U in $\mathbb R^m$

My idea is to prove that each individual set is open since the finite intersection of open sets is open. Starting with the first, I can come up with a function $f : \mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(v,w,x,y,z) = x^2e^{v + w^{100}}-2$ which is continuous since it is made up of powers and exponentials using basic operations. So now I need to show  that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for each open set U in $\mathbb R$, but how do I find a U that contains each open set in $\mathbb R?$

Comment: As suggested, write $S = S_1 \cap S_2$. You do not need to show $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for each open $U$, you already know that! ($f$ is continuous) What you need to do is find an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S_1$ is the preimage of $U$ under $f$ (and then do the same for $S_2$ with a different function $g$).

Answer (score 1):

Here:$$S=f^{-1}\left((2,\infty)\right)\cap g^{-1}\left((-\infty,-1)\right)$$

where $f:\mathbb R^5\to \mathbb R$ is prescribed by $(v,w,x,y,z)\mapsto x^2e^{v+w^{100}}$ and $g:\mathbb R^5\to \mathbb R$ is prescribed by $(v,w,x,y,z)\mapsto xy-z^2$.

Both functions are continuous and the sets $(2,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1)$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R$.

So $S$ is an intersection of open sets, hence is an open set itself.

Answer (score 0):

A function is continous if and only if the preimage of every open set is open.

You have a function from $\mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^2$

$f(v,w,x,y,z)  = (x^2e^{v+w^{100}}),(xy−z^2)$

The set in the co-domain $(2,\infty),(-\infty,-1)$ is an open set.

If the function is continuous, the pre-image is an open set.

Comment: The codomain is $\mathbb{R}$,  not $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Why not $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: You have edited your answer... anyway from OP $f(v,w, x, y,z)=x^2+e^{v+w^{100}}$ so... $f:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}$, moreover what do you mean with "the set in the co-domain $(2,\infty), (-\infty, -1)$ is an open set"?

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation and am accustomed to $(x^2e^{v+w^{100}},xy-z^2)$ and $(2,\infty)\times(-\infty,-1)\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ in situations like this.